# tensorboard stuck when executed at command prompt

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorboard

#### System information

- **Have I written custom code (as opposed to using a stock example script provided in TensorFlow)**: No
- **OS Platform and Distribution (e.g., Linux Ubuntu 16.04)**: Windows 10 Pro 1703
- **TensorFlow installed from (source or binary)**: install binary with GPU version by pip based on Python 3.5.2
- **TensorFlow version (use command below)**:('1.3.0')
- **Python version**: 3.5.2
- **Bazel version (if compiling from source)**:none
- **CUDA/cuDNN version**:cuda v8.0/cuDNN v6,0
- **GPU model and memory**:GeForce GTX 1080 Ti 11GB

#### Describe the problem

I am trying to open TensorBoard after running mnist_with_summaries.py source code from the TensorBoard tutorials (https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r1.3/tensorflow/examples/tutorials/mnist/mnist_with_summaries.py). After running I have got the logs folder. However, 
After I run tensorboard --logdir=/tmp/tensorflow/mnist in cmd, it stuck and did not showing anything else.  I try to use tensorboard --logdir=/tmp/tensorflow/mnist --debug and have the same result. Anyone know what I did wrong?

Answer (score 0):

There is a github issue filed for this: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/12693

Comment: Try `pip install --upgrade tensorflow-tensorboard tensorboard`